# How to delete a selection of textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I'm making a a simple texteditor and for that I'm using a function which gets the selected text of a textarea.

My problem is not getting the selected text but when i add some tags to the selected text, for example bold or italic,  it appends. So what I want is to delete the selection first before adding it to the textarea.

Here's my code:

```
<input type="button" id="bold" value="BOLD"/>
<input type="button" id="undo" value="UNDO"/>
<textarea id="message" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>

var text = [];
var textarea = document.getElementById('message');
//simple texteditor
function edit(tag) {
    var startPos = textarea.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var selection = textarea.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    var surrounder = selection.replace(selection, "<" + tag + ">" + selection + "</" + tag + ">");
    textarea.value += surrounder;
    updatePreview();
    textarea.focus();
}
document.getElementById('bold').onclick = function () {
    edit('b');
};
document.getElementById('undo').onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand('undo',false,null);
};
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to replace the selection with your tags, right? Then why do you append the text to the end of the textarea.value using `+=` operator? This implies that the selection should always be on the end of the message in the textarea.

Comment: Sure @Eddi but when I used the = operator and select a part of the text it replaces the whole text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works for you:

```
var text = [];
var textarea = document.getElementById('message');
//simple texteditor
function edit(tag) {
    var startPos = textarea.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textarea.selectionEnd;
    console.log(startPos);
    var selectionBefore = textarea.value.substring(0, startPos);
    var selection = textarea.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    var selectionAfter = textarea.value.substring(endPos);
    var surrounder = selection.replace(selection, "<" + tag + ">" + selection + "</" + tag + ">");
    var newText = selectionBefore + surrounder + selectionAfter;
    textarea.value = newText;
    updatePreview();
    textarea.focus();
}
document.getElementById('bold').onclick = function () {
    edit('b');
};
document.getElementById('undo').onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand('undo',false,null);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3L659v65/

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for. Could you give a short explanation of what u did compare to what I did?

Comment: You selected your whole old text and added your new Text (selection with tags). He saves the text before and after your selection ( `selectionBefore` and `selectionAfter`). Then he adds the tags at the start and end of your selection like you did within the variable `surrounder`. At the end the new value of your textarea is the `selectionBefore` followed by your `surrounder` and finally by the `selectionAfter`, so that your old text is "deleted".

Comment: Basically you cut the textarea-content in 3 parts: one part is the selected text and the others are before and after that selection. I added 2 variables: `selectionBefore` and `selectionAfter`. `selectionBefore` receives the text from the first character in the textarea until the first selected character. `selectionAfter` receives the full textarea content, but removes all characters until the last selected character. The `newText` variable combines that 3 parts.